# DataBinding with LiveData- after return to fragment from popbackstack, UI update not made

Tags: data-binding, android-livedata

I have a viewmodel with following methods:

```
  private fun getCart(): LiveData<MenuCart?> {
        return Transformations.switchMap(venueId) { venueId ->
            venueId?.let {
                repository.getMenuCart(it)
            } ?: MutableLiveData<MenuCart?>(null)
        }
    }

    fun getCartQty(): LiveData<Int> {
        return Transformations.map(cartVal) {
            it?.items?.count() ?: 0
        }

    }
```

Also have these fields defined inside view model:

```
   val cartVal = getCart()
   val cartQtyVal = getCartQty()
```

Then inside xml have this inside TextView:

```
 android:text="@{viewModel.cartQtyVal.toString()}"
```

And data for xml defined as:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="mypackage.viewmodels.VenueMealsViewModel" />
</data>
```

Inside fragment, have this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val _binding = LayoutVenueMealsMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    _binding!!.lifecycleOwner = this
    _binding!!.viewModel = this.viewModel
    return _binding!!.root
}
```

I use a similar approach in a few places, and it works. But in this case, I have seen a bug where after navigating to another view, and then returning to this fragment, the UI does not update with the latest value of cartQtyVal. Any ideas why? Since the data binding approach is not working, I am temporarily not use data binding, and instead am observing the live data inside the fragment, which works robustly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that when the fragment is re-created after pop backstack, the switchmaps in my view model are not re-triggered. I had to move the setter for the input variable that drives the switchmap to inside the onViewCreated method.